# Bluetooth low energy (BLE) using ESP32 is not connecting to windows 10/11

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-esp32

I developed a code to establish a connection between an ESP32 device and Windows, Mac, and Linux systems using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) technology. While the ESP32 successfully connects to Linux and Mac systems via BLE, it encounters difficulties when attempting to establish a connection with Windows. To program the ESP32, I utilized Arduino IDE version 2.1.1. The objective of the code is to enable the ESP32 to function as a BLE device, allowing it to establish a connection with the target system. Windows is somehow preventing successful BLE connectivity. It is worth noting that I have also implemented battery level characteristics into the code but despite this, the ESP32 can not establish a connection on Windows. I am using esp32 1.0.4 version package instead of 1.0.6 for uploading the code onto the board.

```
#include <BLE2902.h>
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>

// Set the UUIDs for the service, control and data characteristics
#define SERVICE_UUID "fe069420-ec42-4632-b248-42069074f9eb"
#define BAT_SERVICE_UUID "fe069420-ec42-4632-b248-42069074f9ee"
#define CONTROL_CHAR_UUID "fe042069-ec42-4632-b248-69420074f9ec"
#define DATA_CHAR_UUID "fe042069-ec42-4632-b248-69420074f9e0"
#define DATATWO_CHAR_UUID "fe042069-ec42-4632-b248-69420074f9e1"
#define DATATHREE_CHAR_UUID "fe042069-ec42-4632-b248-69420074f9e2"
#define DATAFOUR_CHAR_UUID "fe042069-ec42-4632-b248-69420074f9e3"

// Create global variables for the BLE server, control and data characteristics
BLEServer* pServer;
BLECharacteristic* pControlCharacteristic;
BLECharacteristic* pDataCharacteristic;
BLECharacteristic* pDataTwoCharacteristic;
BLECharacteristic* pDataThreeCharacteristic;
BLECharacteristic* pDataFourCharacteristic;
BLECharacteristic* pBatteryLevelCharacteristic;

BLEService* pBatteryService = NULL;

std::string receivedString;
unsigned long startTime;


// Define the callback function for the control characteristic
class ControlCallback : public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
  void onWrite(BLECharacteristic* pCharacteristic) {
    unsigned long a = micros();
    // Check if the control characteristic was written with a value of 1
    std::string controlVal = pCharacteristic->getValue();
    Serial.print("Control val: ");
    Serial.println(controlVal.c_str());
    // if (controlVal == 1) {
    //   if (receivedString == ""){
    //     startTime = micros();
    //   }
    //   // Read the data characteristic
    //   receivedString += pDataCharacteristic->getValue();
    //   receivedString += pDataTwoCharacteristic->getValue();
    //   receivedString += pDataThreeCharacteristic->getValue();
    //   receivedString += pDataFourCharacteristic->getValue();

    //   // Put the control characteristic back to zero to indicate that the
    //   read is complete unsigned char values[] ={0};
    //   pCharacteristic->setValue(values, 1);
    //   pCharacteristic->notify();
    // } else if (controlVal == 69){
    //   // Read the data characteristics
    //   receivedString += pDataCharacteristic->getValue();
    //   receivedString += pDataTwoCharacteristic->getValue();
    //   receivedString += pDataThreeCharacteristic->getValue();
    //   receivedString += pDataFourCharacteristic->getValue();

    //   unsigned long duration = micros() - startTime;
    //   Serial.print(duration);
    //   Serial.print(" microseconds for ");
    //   Serial.print(receivedString.size());
    //   Serial.print(" bytes. That's an average of ");
    //   Serial.print((double) receivedString.size() / (double) duration *
    //   1000000); Serial.println(" bytes/s.");
    //   Serial.println(receivedString.c_str());
    //   receivedString = "";
    // }
    // Serial.println(micros() - a);
  }
};

// Define the callback function for the BLE server
class ServerCallback : public BLEServerCallbacks {
  void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) { Serial.println("Client connected"); }
  void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
    Serial.println("Client disconnected");
    pServer->startAdvertising();
  }
};

void setup() {
  delay(500);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);

  receivedString.reserve(110000);

  // Create the BLE server
  BLEDevice::init("");
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new ServerCallback());
  BLEService* pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  // Create the control and data characteristics
  pControlCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
      CONTROL_CHAR_UUID, BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE |
                             BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                             BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
                             BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE_NR);
                             
  pBatteryService = pServer->createService(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x180F));

  
  // Create a Battery Level Characteristic
  pBatteryLevelCharacteristic = pBatteryService->createCharacteristic(
    BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2A19),
    BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ
  );

  
  // Set the initial battery level
  unsigned char BATTERY_LEVEL  = 100;
  pBatteryLevelCharacteristic->setValue(&BATTERY_LEVEL, 1);

  // Add the Battery Level Characteristic to the Battery Service
  pBatteryService->addCharacteristic(pBatteryLevelCharacteristic);

  // Start the service
  pBatteryService->start();
  
  auto* bob = new BLE2902();
  bob->setNotifications(true);
  pControlCharacteristic->addDescriptor(bob);

  pDataCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
      DATA_CHAR_UUID, BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE);

  pDataTwoCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
      DATATWO_CHAR_UUID, BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE);

  pDataThreeCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
      DATATHREE_CHAR_UUID, BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE);

  pDataFourCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
      DATAFOUR_CHAR_UUID, BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE);

  // Set the callback function for the control characteristic
  pControlCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new ControlCallback());

  // Start the service and advertise the BLE server
  pService->start();
  BLEAdvertising* pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->start();
  Serial.println("Started up");
}

void loop() {
  // Allow the BLE device to process events
  // BLEDevice::handleEvents();
  // Serial.print("rarri\n");
  delay(500);
}
```

I have tried to upload the code on the board using 1.0.4 instead of 1.0.6 esp32 board package, but still the esp32 is not being connected. The esp32 is being found by the windows, but it can not connect to the board at all. Can anyone please help me out

Comment: How do you try to establish a connection via Windows? Keep in Mind that BLE works different than Bluetooth Classic. A phone usually requires an app to communicate with BLE devices and Windows might not be able to connect to your device through the Bluetooth Settings. Try to look for your device using a generic BLE observation tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-desktop).